# Xcode fails building Google Analytics SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

I'm following the instructions in [Google Analytics for iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/53459/google-analytics-ios), and once I've set the SDK files and frameworks, I get these errors when I try to build the project:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:
  -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore propertyRecordForTrackingId:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
"_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:
  -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore bindRecord:toUpsertStatement:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
```

and a lot more like this, has somebody else experienced this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you link your project with libsqlite3.dylib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial seems to be out of date to me. Have you added all the libraries?

```
CoreData.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
libz.dylib
libsqlite3.dylib
libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a
```

I recommend to go to the official documentation.

- [No using CocoaPods](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sdk-download?hl=es)
- [Using CocoaPods](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?hl=es)

Comment: Thanks, I was missing `libsqlite3.dylib`